# Azure Pipelines build fails with Error MSB3774: Could not find SDK "Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement, Version=10.0"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Sorry for my bad English.

UWP solution created with Windows Template Studio, targeting 17763 SDK. I have selected FeedbackHub resource, which installs and references Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement NuGet package. On my local machine the solution builds and runs as expected, but when Azure Pipelines runs the build fails in VSBuild with Error MSB3774, stating that Microsoft Store Services SDK isn't installed.

I adapted the PowerShell script [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897161/appveyor-build-error-msb3774-could-not-find-sdk-microsoft-admediator-universal) to download and install the SDK, but the build still fails.

How can I tell Azure Pipelines to install Microsoft Store Services SDK before VSBuild?

My `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
# Universal Windows Platform
# Build a Universal Windows Platform project using Visual Studio.
# Add steps that test and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x86|x64|ARM'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  appxPackageDir: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    platform: 'x86'
    solution: '$(solution)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxPackageDir)" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload'
```

I thank for any help I can have.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I resolved it by making sure I was using the same Windows SDK on the devops machine as I was targeting in my app. That resolved this issue for me.